# Project 2D image on a surface

Tags: web, augmented-reality

I'm building a web app that projects a 2d image on a flat surface. For this to work I need a marker that I can recognize on the surface.

My idea is to use the *[QR code finder and alignment patterns](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mohammad_Nazim2/publication/295584462/figure/fig2/AS:332147958272001@1456201652782/QR-codes-structure-1-Finder-Pattern-It-is-detecting-position-of-QR-code-structure-is.png)* as a marker to figure out orientation, distortion and distance. The orientation and distortion part is easy with QR codes. For the distance I thought that I can print the finder patterns with a fixed distance between them of 1cm and calculate the distance to scale the image accordingly.

Now I have 2 questions:

- Is this a good approach?
- Is there a better way or marker that I can use to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Have you tried jsartoolkit5 or AR.js both provide tracking capabilities? In fact, AR.js builds on top of jsartoolkit5. And there are examples out there on how to place a 2d image on the surface.

Comment: I have seen AR.js and it uses a finder pattern as well. However, it was very slow on my phone. Will try out jsartoolkit5.

Comment: Keep me posted how it goes